# Why popping to root view controller results in calling viewDidLoad sometimes?

Tags: ios

I have a navigation based application and in the child view I have a button, tapping on which results in calling the popToRootViewController method.

```
-(IBAction)popToRootViewController
{
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

This should result in calling the viewWillAppear method of the rootViewController and it is happening in most of the cases. However, occasionally viewDidLoad of rootViewController is called. I am not able to find the reason behind it. Does any one has any idea why viewDidLoad is called sometimes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS 5 and Earlier, the System May Unload Views When Memory Is Low:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html

Answer (score 0):

**viewDidLoad** is called once when view controller's view is loaded first time.

**viewWillAppear** will be called after viewDidLoad method when view controller's view is loaded first time.

Now when ever u **push or pop controller in navigationController**, the **visible controller's viewWillApper** method will be called surely.

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidLoad`, as the name implies, is called just after a view controller has loaded its view. If a view controller is no longer the frontmost controller, it may release its view to save memory (and it used to call `viewWillUnload` and `viewDidUnload` which are now deprecated in iOS 6). If this happens, when it comes to front again (or whenever something calls `thecontroller.view`), it will recreate the view (if is not Nib-based, it will call `loadView`), and then call `viewDidLoad`.